# Not getting the right input from my object variable

Tags: javascript, variables, null, numbers, getelementbyid

I did some sleuthing to see if I could find out why my code wasn't working, but I don't entirely understand what I should be looking for!

What's happening is that when a user inputs a guess into the textbox "playerinput" and then hits submit (which runs the game function), my program is outputting "You have guessed too low (). You have 4/3/2/1... guesses."

What's driving me crazy is () is where the guess is supposed to go. It's stuck at 0 for some reason (I think).

Is my code generating a number correctly and calling it correctly?

```
var NumberGame={
playerinput:document.getElementById("playerinput").value,

computernumber:0,
count:0,
output:document.getElementById("CPUoutput"),
guess:document.getElementById("guessbutton"),
randomnumber: function(){
 NumberGame.computernumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
return NumberGame.computernumber;
    }

}

function newgame() {
    window.alert("A new game has begun. Your guesses have been reset to 0, and the new number has been generated.");
    location.reload();
    }

function game() {

if (NumberGame.count===0){
    NumberGame.computernumber=NumberGame.randomnumber();
}

    if (NumberGame.playerinput < NumberGame.computernumber)
{
    NumberGame.count++;
    NumberGame.output.innerHTML = "You have guessed too low. (" + NumberGame.playerinput + ") You have used up " + NumberGame.count + " guesses.";
}
    else if (NumberGame.playerinput > NumberGame.computernumber) 
{
   NumberGame.count++;
    NumberGame.output.innerHTML = "You have guessed too high. (" + NumberGame.playerinput + ") You have used up " + NumberGame.count + " guesses.";

}
    else if (NumberGame.playerinput === NumberGame.computernumber) 
{
    NumberGame.output.innerHTML = "<h1>You Win!</h1>";
        newgame();

}
    if (NumberGame.count === 5)
{
    NumberGame.output.innerHTML = "<h1>You Lose!</h1>";
    newgame();

}


}
```

UPDATED: Here is the HTML, by request. Going to try some of your suggestions. Couple things I didn't understand though, will require more research.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>KevinPietteProject1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">

</head>
<body>


    <div id="gamebody">
        <h1>-- Number Guessing Game -- 
    </h1>
<p >Guess the number between 1-20.</p>
<input id="playerinput" type="text" maxlength="2" autofocus size="4" />
<br>
<input type="button" id="guessbutton" value="Guess!" onClick="game()"/>
<br>
<input type="button" value="New Game" onclick="newgame();" />
<p>
    The object of the game is to guess what number the computer is thinking of.<br> The number is always between 1 and 20. Everytime you win, lose, or hit the new game button, a new number is generated. <br> Every new game, you begin with 5 guesses.

    <br>
        <div id="imagediv">
            <img id="thepicture" src="Images/neutral.png" height="120" width="120">
        </div>
    <br>


                <div id="Guessesleft">
                </div>


    </p>

            <div id="CPUoutput">
            </div>
    </div> 

<script src="rewrittenscript.js">
// Here, I've put the script at the bottom of the page so the DOM loads in the right order
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the `HTML` as well

Comment: Could you console.log() your player input?

Comment: Is the output Null or 0? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define NumberGame, you have this:

```
playerinput:document.getElementById("playerinput").value,
```

This sets player input to the value at the time you are defining NumberGame. This value will never change. You are basically assigning a string to playerInput. I assume this isn't what you wanted.

What you need to do is to grab the new input value every time you call your game() function. One thing you can do is just define playerinput everytime you call game()

```
function game() {
    NumberGame.playerinput = parseInt(document.getElementById("playerinput").value)
```

Comment: @Sushanth-- No he is right, the value only get read on function call!

Comment: this is what worked for me- the function started correctly drawing the value from the input box.

Comment: however, i must say now its not working in a different way...When the user correctly guesses the number, nothing happens. It's not correctly registering that the user got the correct answer. if you know the name of that issue, (like, are my  else if statements coded correctly? is there a correct order in coding it, such as 'if, else if, else'?) then I could do some reading up on it and then debug my code

Comment: Ah, you should also convert the input into a number. Right now it is a string. So it is comparing with "===" between string to a number, which will always be false. I've modified my answer to fix this.

Comment: An alternative way would be to use "==" instead of "===" in your "if" statement as well

Comment: @Yes the order should be `if...else if...else`. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp. I updated my answer, since you have to set the radix to 10, if anybody puts into the field 013. Check this for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
onkeyup=""
```

In your html

```
onkeyup="NumberGame.playerinput = this.value"
```

I do not see when you call NumberGame at all, but if you only run game() on submit, you should encorporate NumberGame into the function you call!

Or try to write

```
playerinput : function() {return parseInt(document.getElementById("playerinput").value),10}();
```

then the value gets updated everytime you call

```
NumberGame.playerinput
```

Comment: That is not the issue here !! . The variable is a property of the `NumberGame` object . As long as one accesses it using it, always gives you the updated value

Comment: @Sushanth-- I got the question wrong, problem seems to be the player input.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Could you please encorporate my updated answer into your consideration of downvoting it?